# Ascii Value Calculations

Tags: c++, ascii

Prompt:

Ask the user for a single letter.  Then calculate and state the sum total of all of the ascii values from A to that letter (assume small letters).

--

I don't know how to go about this problem. I've written some introductory code but don't know how to actually code the real calculation part of the program.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char letter;
int j;

cout<<"Enter single letter: ";
cin>>letter;

for(int i=65;i<=letter;i++)
{
    j=j+j++;
}

cout<<"Sum is "<<j;

return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `char()` and this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) are your friends.

Comment: Since the letter is stored in a `char` but is always converted to an `int` in an expression, you only need to know how to get the ASCII value of the letter 'A', and know how to add up integers.  It is that simple — assuming your computer uses an ASCII-based (e.g. ISO 8859 or Unicode) code set.  You do know how to write a `for` loop, don't you?

Comment: Why use a loop where the answer can be calculated with a simple formula from the middle school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
j = j + j++;
```

Should be:

```
j += i;
```

because `i` represents every ASCII value from `A` to `letter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what value is in j before the for loop starts adding in to it.